# Show that the set $\{x^2\sin x ,\ \cos x-2x\}$ is lineary independent

Tags: linear-algebra, trigonometry

I need to show that the set $\{x^2\sin x ,\ \cos x-2x\}$ is either independent or not.

So, I create the equation $ax^2\sin x + b(\cos x-2x) = 0$ (where $a,b \in\mathbb R$), but how should I proceed? For which  values  of $x$ should I check the equation?

Comment: Welcome to math.SE, on this site we use MathJaX to format our maths. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/145141) you can find a basic tutorial.

Comment: A good start (and almost finish) is to let $x=0$.

Comment: Are you familiar with the notion/purpose of a Wronskian?

Comment: @AndréNicolas I started with x = 0 but which other values should I use and why?

Comment: @Xoque55 No, I don't know what it means.

Comment: @gebruiker thanks, I will read the tutorial.

Comment: Putting $x=0$ we find that $b(\cos x-2x)$ is identically $0$, so $b=0$. Thus $ax^2\sin x$ is identically $0$. That forces $a=0$.

Comment: Hi Ido, this equation holds for all values of $x$. In fact it is like an identity. So put $x=0, x=\pi/2$ then we get $a=b=0$. That is the given set is independent.